# http://sorgalla.com - jCarousel / jQuery - Callback not firing with bind on Click Anchor

Tags: jquery, callback, click, anchor, jcarousel

I am a bit of a novice to Javascript I have to have to say - however I am prepared to give things a go. I can't seem to get the following click callback to work . It does not fire and there is no message on the Javascript console.

Can anyone see anything glaringly wrong or incorrect in what I have done . 
This is based on http://sorgalla.com - jCarousel on top of jQuery. It is based on a simple example. The code which does not work is :

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:1, wrap: 'circular'
    });
 console.log('ready');
});

jQuery('#mycarousel a').bind('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><a id="test" href="#">Click</a></li>
...
...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any pointers would be most appreciated. 
thank you , Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Embedding calls to : console.log() in jQuery to see what is going on and the following resolves the issue :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:1, wrap: 'circular'
    });
 console.log('ready');

jQuery('#mycarousel a').bind('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
});

});
```

click event now works.